# Change from pixel to micron when using matplotlib plt.imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

As the title suggests I am trying to update the axis units when using plt.imshow on .tif images captured from a microscope. Pixel --> microns. lets say 1 pixel is 0.5 microns.

I have made secondary Celsius axes in the past using callbacks, but didn't have luck with imshow. I briefly used imshow parameters origin and extent. It appears those are parameters for orientation. My apologies for providing code as I am writing this remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of this answer, let's take the following example code for `imshow`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.uniform(size=(1024, 1024))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data)
ax.set_xlabel('x pixel index')
ax.set_ylabel('y pixel index')

plt.show()
```

[image: 1024x1024 grid of random pixels with x- and y-axes going from 0 to 1024]

In this figure, the axis ticks range from 0 to 1024 (pixels). Instead, you would like them to range from 0 to 512 microns. A slightly complicated and cumbersome approach would be to get the x and y tick values, divide them by two, and set the new values as tick labels. A different approach is to create a custom [tick formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html), essentially a function to convert between the tick value and the tick label formatting.

In your case, creating a `FuncFormatter` is probably the best option. Here, you define a function that takes two inputs (a tick value `x` and a position `pos`) and returns a string containing the tick label. There are a few different methods to define such a formatter (see the link above), but the simplest is to pass a lambda function to the `set_major_formatter` method of your axis' `xaxis` and `yaxis` objects. See the example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np

data = np.random.uniform(size=(1024, 1024))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data)

formatter = lambda x, pos: x * 0.5  # 0.5 is the resolution
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

ax.set_xlabel('x position (μm)')
ax.set_ylabel('y position (μm)')

plt.show()
```

With this example, your plot will be as follows:

[image: same grid of random pixels, but x- and y-axes now go from 0 to 512]

Note that decimal points have now been added as Python's default float-to-string behaviour is to include one decimal. You can change your formatter to return a formatted string without any decimals:

```
formatter = lambda x, pos: f'{(x * 0.5):.0f}'
```

[image: x- and y-axes without decimal points]

Essentially, you can now make your formatter as simple or as complicated as you like.

Comment: Thanks luuk, this helps a lot. I appreciate the clear example.